# Streaming music from server using cmus/ssh

Tags: ssh, stream, debian, raspberry-pi

I got a server running at home, and I want to stream music from it at work. I dont want to mount a samba-folder or something.

Is it possible to playback music via cmus (running on server) and ssh (ssh command or putty on win)? The sound output needs to be the speakers of the remote-pc, not the server. Is this possible?

I dont get this working.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in Linux it is very possible. Found a forum thread with exactly what you need. You might have to search around but this should [get you started](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/playing-audio-files-over-ssh-connection-linux-linux-432640/)

A short explanation is: It's pretty bandwidth heavy to stream audio over the internet. An easy solution is to use Gnump3, which can down sample music. Gnump3 is not really a "broadcast" kinda app. More like access to your music remotely.

Answer (score 11):

Tutorial I wrote up for Linux:

---

## Play music over SSH using **CMUS** and **SSHFS**

#### Note: This works great for Chromebooks using [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton)

#### 1. Install **sshfs**:

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

#### 2. Install **cmus**:

```
sudo apt-get install cmus
```

#### 3. Add **ssh key** with home computer:

`ssh-copy-id` is your friend.

(see some other tutorial)

#### 4. **Create** a mount folder:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/example/mount/location
```

(edit this location to reflect a directory structure you want. ie if you want to mount a `music` folder, mount something like `/mnt/example/music`)

#### 5. **Mount** folder with sshfs

```
sudo sshfs -p PORT_NUMBER -o allow_other -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa user@192.XXX.XXX.XXX:./folder/to/mount /mnt/example/location
```

> The `-o allow_other` parameter is very important, as you won't have access to the mount otherwise. PORT_NUMBER can be ignored if you use the standard 443 port, else set it to the correct value.

#### 6. **Add music** to your collection:

From terminal, launch cmus:

```
$ cmus
```

Type `:` to bring up the cmus command line and type:

```
add /mnt/example/location
```

This will add music to your collection. For the ins-and-outs of cmus keyboard shortcuts type `man cmus` from terminal.

#### 7. Unmount drive when done:

```
sudo umount /mnt/example/location
```

### Other notes:

Might need to make sure cmus is configured to use pulse audio, not alsa. I think this is done by editing `~/.cmus/autosave` and setting the parameter `set output_plugin=pulse`, but I didn't have to do this so I think you can safely ignore this.

Comment: Note that it is not mandatory to define an ssh key and IdentityFile if you don't bother typing your password, which `sshfs` will prompt for.